# Calculating genus of graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

How to calculate genus of arbitrary graph? I am interested in any algorithm, even it based on full search.

Comment: What research did you do? It would be a shame for us to duplicate your efforts by looking for an answer in the same place as you did. (Such as, say, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding#Computational_complexity), which says the problem is **NP**-hard and gives some algorithms going back to the 1970s.)

Comment: I need to determine the genus a given graph with 10 vertices and 26 edges. I found out that the graph is not planar. Also I built embedding on torus without one edge. It remains to understand the graph has genus 1 or 2.

Comment: If "full search" is sufficient for you, why not just code that? Brute-force algorithms are typically simple. I don't see what your point is here (especially in the light of @DavidRicherby's very accurate remarks).

Comment: @Raphael: I have found no published algorithms for coding. Please point me to one of them.

Comment: @Interloper Nobody would embarrass themselves by submitting a brute-force algorithm for publication (or so I hope), let alone by actually publishing it (hoping even harder).

Comment: @Raphael: Even brute-force in this case there is not a trivial task. What is the set of elements to iterate?

Comment: "All" embeddings? (Note that even a naive [Google Scholar query](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=algorithm+genus+graph&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C39) quickly yields [an article that claims the problem is NP-complete](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0196-6774(89)90006-0); the "$\in$ NP"-part of the proof should answer your question. But then, David pointed that out already so I have to assume you don't want to do any reading yourself.)

Comment: I read the materials on the topic. I have not found a description of the structure of embeddings which may be used for coding. You can point on the formal description of this structure?

Comment: @Interloper As long as you are not prepared to follow some links and dig into literature, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way that always works and is relatively easy to turn into code is [Edmond's rotational embedding scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_system). Let $G$ be a connected graph with vertices $V(G)=\{v_1, v_1, \dotsc, v_p\}$. For every vertex $v\in V(G)$ choose a permutation $\pi_v$ of the vertices adjacent to $v$. Then the collection of permutations $\pi_{v_i}$ determine an embedding of $G$ in a orientable surface $S_n$ of genus $n$, and, conversely, every embedding of $G$ in $S_n$ is determined by some collection of permutations as described above.

For example, consider $K_4$ with vertices labeled $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and permutations
$$\begin{align}
\pi_1 &= (2\ 4\ 3)\\
\pi_2 &= (1\ 3\ 4)\\
\pi_3 &= (1\ 2\ 4)\\
\pi_4 &= (3\ 1\ 2)
\end{align}$$

The permutations will correspond to the counterclockwise order in which the adjacent vertices are encountered in the embedding (hence the term *rotation*). The permutations give rise to permutations, $\pi$, of the directed edges, defined by $\pi((v_i, v_j)) = (v_j, \pi_j(v_i))$. In the example above, we'll have
$$\begin{align}
\pi((2, 1))&=(1, \pi_1(2)) = (1, 4)\\
\pi((1, 4))&=(4, \pi_4(1)) = (4, 2)\\
\pi((4, 2))&=(2, \pi_2(4)) = (2, 1)
\end{align}$$
and we're back where we started, having generated a 2-cell $(2, 1, 4)$. Starting the process with the directed edge $(1, 2)$ gives rise to a 2-cell $(1,2,3,4,1,3,2,4,3)$ and we stop here, having used all 12 directed edges in $K_4$. We know that for an orientable 2-cell embedding in $S_n$ of a graph with $p$ vertices, $q$ edges, $r$ faces we'll have 
$$
p-q+r=2-2n
$$
in this case we have $p-q+r=4-6+2=0=2-2n$ so $n=1$, meaning that $K_4$ has genus no larger than 1.

Of course, as presented this is a *terribly* inefficient algorithm, since there will be factorially many permutations for each vertex. There are some tweaks that will speed this up and there are some more modern approaches/modifications one could use (Edmond's paper came out in 1960), but the upshot is still that there's no efficient way to compute the genus of a graph.

Comment: Ad summary/judgement: there's a *huge* gap between polynomial and "$n^n$" so I don't think the P/NP-situation should be an argument for why we should be satisfied with this algorithm.

Comment: @Raphael. Agreed. My reason for using this was that it translates easily to code. The OP did say, after all, that any algorithm, even a god-awful one, would be appreciated. I've edited the last paragraph to provide what I hope is a better summation.